# Google Maps Polygon Incorrectly Rendered

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to draw a semi-circle in google maps using Geodesics Points between 2 latitude and longitudes.

I found a place that had exactly what I needed: http://maps.forum.nu/temp/gm_bearing.html

```
It was using the API V2 and I need the V3.
```

So I converted it.

The problem im having is that the semi-circle isnt being drawn correctly and i cant figure out why.

This is what happens when the semi-circle is drawn.
[image]

But when I zoom out or I make the semi-circle smaller it looks fine.
[image]

I have reproduced the issue in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/4dRB2/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove these line in the drawCircle function:

```
var basePoints = calculateGeodesicPoints(circlePoints[circlePoints.length - 1], circlePoints[0]);
while (basePoints.length) {
  circlePoints.push(basePoints.shift());
}
```

[image]
http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/draw-semi-circle.html

Comment: i cant believe i didn't find this before. Thanks so much.