# Google Maps API v3 - circle sector

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry

I would like to draw sector of circle on map defined by point, radius, startAngle and stopAngle. I found lots of exmaples but with polygons etc whitch was too complicated for my case.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

a Circle is an object with no defined sides.  Only a radius and a center point.
You are required to use a polygon to build a semi circle as it is a two sied object

**There is not always an easy way out in coding,  and typicaly they are the bad ways to do things** (unless your talking about somthing like JQ/Bootstrap)

Here is a fairly stright forware implementation

http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/draw-semi-circle.html

This was refered in this question
[Google Maps Polygon Incorrectly Rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993938/google-maps-polygon-incorrectly-rendered)

they even provide a working example for you to rip apart
http://maps.forum.nu/temp/gm_bearing.html