# How to draw a filled arc in Angular Google Maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have a requirement where I want to draw a circle with four quadrants, all four quadrants with a specified angle and radius from a center point. Like below:

[image]

But not with the markers on the circumference. I should be able to provide an **angle of arc**, **radius** and **center point**. How can I achieve with the Angular Google Maps?

I'm able to get the center point and set radius and draw a circle using `agm-circle` directive.

I've referenced this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959636/11253641

Comment: Not sure that AGM has a directive for arc, but you can implement it based on the solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956616/draw-circles-arc-on-google-maps.

Comment: Just like in the example given, it uses Polygon rather than a circle, Likewise, maybe we can draw an arc using AGM polygon directive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a polygon directive

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
  <agm-polyline>
      <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let point of arcPoints" [latitude]="point.latitude" [longitude]="point.longitude">
      </agm-polyline-point>
  </agm-polyline>
</agm-map>
```

and in the component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.arcPoints = drawArc(center, initialBearing, finalBearing, radius);
  }
```

Comment: I'm using Angular Google Maps, which doesn't have Google Maps functions like center.lat(), center.DestinationPoint(), etc methods, which does not work for me.