# Curved line overlay on top of Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I see we can draw polylines and circles on top of Google map by this API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes
Is there any way to draw a curved line on top of a Google map?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for... https://stackoverflow.com/q/24956616/10221765

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can draw by following js code,

```
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: { lat: 0, lng: -180 },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
  const flightPlanCoordinates = [
    { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214 },
    { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821 },
    { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431 },
    { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027 },
  ];
  const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

you can follow this example :

> [https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/master/dist/samples/polyline-simple/jsfiddle][1]